# Submit only works on second click

Tags: php, jquery, forms, recaptcha

I have a form with a verification through Google reCaptcha. But now I have to click the submit button twice. I can't find the reason.

My form is build like this (Smarty):

```html
<form method="post" id="form">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="misdaden">
     <table>
        {foreach from=$misdaden item=item}
           <tr>
                <td class="coll">{$item['id']}</td>
                <td class="coll">{$item['name']}</td>
                <td class="coll">{$item['minmoney']}</td>
                <td class="coll">{$item['maxmoney']}</td>
                <td class="coll">{$item['difficulty']}</td>
                <td class="coll">{$item['percentage']}%</td>
                <td class="coll"><input type="radio" style="width:20px;" name="value" value={$item['id']} /></td>
           </tr>
        {/foreach}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Misdaad plegen!" name="submit" class="submit" />
    <!--input class="button good large" name="submit" type="submit" value="Pleeg misdaad!"-->
</form>
```

My script is (JQuery):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('6LesiMAUAAAAAAJ8G94kKbXxJj62_U2ajn-dzJzF', {action:'misdaden'})
              .then(function(token) {
                    $('#form').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'+ token +'">');
                    $('#form').unbind('submit').submit();
                });
    });
});
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jquery script, you are unbinding the submit event handler for form on execution of captcha which is not required.
Just submit the form, see below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('6LesiMAUAAAAAAJ8G94kKbXxJj62_U2ajn-dzJzF', {action:'misdaden'})
              .then(function(token) {
                    $('#form').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'+ token +'">');
                    $('#form').submit();
                });
    });
});
```

Comment: If I do this, the button doesn't submit anymore.The script was copied from this site, explanation of the reason of the unbind is there: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/example-of-how-to-add-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form--cms-33752

Comment: I just see some example and found that you should make changes in script. See my updated answer